# How to relocate the django admin site below root?

Tags: django, django-admin

The contrib admin site of Django is a perfect starting point for simple in-house applications that lots of people use.

I've done a bit of searching and seen the discussions of media and tools for working with and merging static media for the admin site.  But it is still pretty fragmented and opaque.

Assume I have a site "mysite" with an application "myapp" that is derived from the admin app.

I would really appreciate an example of relocating mysite and myapp, including the admin app, onto a web server where it is not at the root url.

I think this use case would flush out a lot of the issues and confusion that I see people have.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you want to do is use the `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = '/path/not/at/root/of/domain'` option in your settings.py file.  No trailing /.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#force-script-name

I hope I'm understanding your question right and I hope this helps solve it.

Edit:  oops gave link to old docs...updated with new docs version

Edit2: Here is another link describing this [here at djangoproject](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/fastcgi/#forcing-the-url-prefix-to-a-particular-value) again.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why this got voted down (I didn't do it).  As I hack on this, I'm finding that careful use of "../" and setting up the URLs files can make it work.  I will post when I have an example worked out.

Comment: Here is another post I just found that seems to be the same thing here on SO as well.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627013/django-apache-address-problem  I really wish people would say why they downvote something.  If you have a reason to downvote something explain so all of us can benefit from our mistakes please.

Comment: Yes, that is a relevant post, thank you.  Yikes, I see another down vote with no explanation.  I suspect that the down-voters know what I am discovering - that careful and consistent url design and usage will "just work".  But I have yet to see anyone who gives this example.

Comment: And I agree with you that down-voting without an explanation is lazy.  Useful but lazy.

Comment: Yes, if that is what they are downvoting about then I can agree somewhat.  However, there could be times when, due to other (not even necessarily django) things running on the same site, url design may not make sense. (as in subpath type stuff anyway)